Why isn’t my hyperlink being recognized by search engines for SEO?
I'm working on improving the SEO for my website, and I've added several hyperlinks to my content. However, when I check the page using SEO tools, it seems like the links aren't being recognized by search engines.
Here's a snippet of my HTML:
<strike>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kampus Entrepreneur</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="https://www.ciputra.ac.id" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">Kampus Entrepreneur</a>
</body>
</html>

The links work perfectly fine for users, but they don’t seem to contribute to SEO rankings. Is there something wrong with how I've implemented the links? Could the styling or something else be affecting how search engines crawl them?

Perhaps edit your post to show the results of the SEO tools which make you think the links are not being crawled.  "Check the page using SEO tools" is a very vague statement.
Your expectations about ranking sounds like you might just not understand how links work for SEO - internal links are for improving crawlability and relevance for users as well as Google.  Unlike external links, they don't increase PageRank, though may help focus the existing PageRank on pages based on their importance.
From the information currently given, my assumption would be that the tools are showing external links (which if relevant may help ranking), and not internal links.
Also, SEO tools rarely give live data - their crawlers are far less powerful than Google's.  It can take a while for new information to appear.

Overall, Richard has answered your question. I just want to add that internal links only assist in SEO but do not carry a direct impact.
Search engine bots visit your site and also index pages through internal links.
